# Not able to resolve conflicts after merging branches

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I am using Android Studio and recently tried merging branches.  It popped up with the conflicts as normal, but when I hit the "resolve conflicts" option the dialog would not pop up.

After doing some searching I tried to just manually deal with the conflicts as other people said they were able to get it working after they did that.  It did not work for me.  I am still getting the same error, which is shown below.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thank you.

```
Assertion failed: The conflict not found for file: C:/Users/Ephraim/Google     Drive/personal/working_apps/ClashToolkit/app/src/main/java/com/clashtoolkit/clashtoolkit/ui/MainBuilderActivity.java(app/src/main/java/com/clashtoolkit/clashtoolkit/ui/MainBuilderActivity.java)
Full ls-files output: 
 M 100644 f284f4c33978d4b052e7adad4ddada28e99c3e74 1    app/app-release.apk       M 100644 43d336e4919e7d6878d73e74323f62e7d0a291a6 2   app/app-release.apk M 100644 e452f4ee580d8acee1ffdcbf903defb148fd0a5e 3 app/app-release.apk M 100644 856ec3aa1267897a06343ecad067e4e3573ec221 1 app/build.gradle M 100644 47eca345aba4c76514c916b6c67c411748dca162 2    app/build.gradle M 100644 8903ad433e056f96fe64300f9d3cd8b28ea333d2 3    app/build.gradle M 100644 32de04232a98985e94ec67e3e81331b1bc9321e3 2    app/src/main/assets/db.json M 100644 63aacbde235f49491a71ab682bd1e602f8068aba 3 app/src/main/assets/db.json M 100644 c17e8a1f613060eb82cdf8fc6bf8f15a2c393853 1 app/src/main/java/com/clashtoolkit/clashtoolkit/UI/MainBuilderActivity.... (show balloon)


java.lang.Throwable
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.assertTrue(Logger.java:146)
at git4idea.merge.GitMergeProvider$MyMergeSession.<init>(GitMergeProvider.java:294)
at git4idea.merge.GitMergeProvider.createMergeSession(GitMergeProvider.java:227)
at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.merge.MultipleFileMergeDialog.<init>(MultipleFileMergeDialog.java:139)
at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.impl.AbstractVcsHelperImpl.showMergeDialog(AbstractVcsHelperImpl.java:596)
at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.AbstractVcsHelper.showMergeDialog(AbstractVcsHelper.java:128)
at git4idea.actions.GitResolveConflictsAction.actionPerformed(GitResolveConflictsAction.java:73)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:182)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:311)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:958)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:281)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:109)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Comment: How about doing it in cmd line?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  But if you give me the command I will try.

Comment: Suppose we are merging dev to master. `git checkout master;git merge dev;`, and now conflicts come. `git status` to see which files have conflicts. Open these files one by one, find the `<<<<=====>>>>` parts, remove the unwanted lines and keep the wanted lines, save and exit. `git add` and `git commit` to finish the merge.

Comment: unfortunately that did not work.  It is still giving me errors.  After doing that it said it cannot completed the push because it is incomplete and needs to be complete for a merge.

Comment: ok, did finally get it to work.  It seemed when I tried before I had skipped a file.  So manually adding (via the cmd) did the trick.  Thank you!